# Pushouts and Pullbacks in Category Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

How would one prove existence of pushouts and pullbacks where the objects are vector spaces and the morphisms are linear transformations?

Comment: Use the theorem that says that pushouts/pullbacks can be constructed from coproducts/products and coequalisers/equalisers.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:U\to W$ and $g:V\to W$ be linear mappings. Their pullback can be given by the embedding of the subspace $\{(u,v)\,\mid\,f(u)=g(v)\}$ of $U\times V$.

If $f:U\to V$ and $g:U\to W$, then their pushout is $V\oplus W\,/\sim\ $ where $V\oplus W$ is basically the same as $V\times W$, and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by the relations $f(u)\sim g(u)$ for all $u\in U$.